# Comportamiento anormal de un runnable al salir de una actividad y volver a iniciarla

Tags: android

Resulta que en una `Activity` estoy utilizando un `grid` de imágenes alimentado por un `Adapter`, que se refresca gracias un `Runnable` que ejecuto cada cierto tiempo, y es siempre el mismo (ej: 500 milisegundos) y no lo varío en ningún sitio del código.

He sobreescrito el método `onBackPressed`, porque necesito guardar al finalizar la actividad y cierro la Activity con un `finish()` e inicio la anterior actividad a partir de la cual empecé.

El problema que tengo es que si vuelvo a iniciar la misma actividad, el `timer` deja de comportarse adecuadamente y en lugar de ejecutarse cada X milisegundos que le indico, se ejecuta cuando le apetece, que generalmente es menos de los X milisegundos y no es una cantidad constante. De manera que mi grid no refresca adecuadamente las imágenes.

¿A alguien le ha pasado algo similar?

La actividad que contiene el grid la tengo implementada así...

```
    public class PantallaTragaperrasBotonera extends FragmentActivity {
        private Tragaperras juegoTragaperras;
        private GridView gridview;
        private ImageAdapter imageadapter;              
        public byte estado;

        //se le pasa como parámetro al INTENT
        private int numEjecuciones;

        //los tres primeros y el Ya normal para el resto.

        private Runnable swapImages = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Log.d("DEBUGUEANDO", "PantallaTragaperrasBotonera: INICIO private Runnable swapImages = new Runnable(){ public void run(){);");

                //Si no se han pulsado los tres botones         
                if (!juegoTragaperras.finalizado() && !contador.tiempoFinalizado()){
                        Log.d("DEBUGEANDO","if (!juegoTragaperras.finalizado() && !contador.tiempoFinalizado()){");
                        mostrarImagenes(this);                      
                        juegoTragaperras.incrementarPosicionesMomentosParo();

                }else{
                    Log.d("DEBUGUEANDO","PantallaTragaperrasBotonera: }else{");
                    //Se muestra el cuadro de diálogo con la puntuación obtenida
                    if (estado == 0){

                        estado = 1;
                        gridview.postDelayed(swapImages, 0);

                    //Se muestra el grid con las animaciones pertinentes y la animación del contador
                    }else if (estado ==1){
                        gridview.postDelayed(swapImages,0);
                    }else if (estado == 2){                     
                        imageadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                            
                        gridview.setAdapter(imageadapter);
                        gridview.invalidateViews();
                        gridview.postDelayed(swapImages, (Tragaperras.ganado() ? 5000:1000));                       
                        estado = 3;
                    //finalmente se finaliza la actividad
                    }else if (estado == 3){                     
                        try{

                            Intent i = new Intent(PantallaTragaperrasBotonera.this, PantallaObjetivo.class);
                            i.putExtra("com.example.HappyBoom.PUNTOS_CONTADOR", contador.obtenerPuntuacionContador());
                            PantallaTragaperrasBotonera.this.startActivity(i);

                            finish();
                            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                        }catch(Exception e){}               
                    }               
                }               
            }

        };

        //para manejar el evento OnTimerListener    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);          
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tragaperrasbotonera);

            //Obtenemos las variables entre actividades         
            Bundle extra = this.getIntent().getExtras();
            puntosContador = extra.getLong("com.example.HappyBoom.PUNTOS_CONTADOR");
            numEjecuciones = extra.getInt("com.example.HappyBoom.NUMERO_EJECUCIONES");
            numEjecuciones = 1;

            juegoTragaperras = Tragaperras.getInstance();
            juegoTragaperras.reiniciarInstancia();

            gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvTragaperras);         
            gridview.setNumColumns(juegoTragaperras.getNumeroColumnas());
            imageadapter = new ImageAdapter(this, ImageAdapter.TipoJuego.TRAGAPERRAS);
            gridview.setAdapter(imageadapter);                              
            gridview.postDelayed(swapImages, 0);
            //...
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {           
            guardarDatos();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SeleccionaJuegos.class);
            if (i != null)this.startActivity(i);
            finish();
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();      
        }

        private void guardarDatos(){
            //guarda los datos
        }       

        /**
         * Muestra las imágenes dependiendo del array de estados que el juego haya alcanzado.
         * @param runnable
         */     
        private void mostrarImagenes(Runnable runnable){
            imageadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                
            gridview.setAdapter(imageadapter);
            gridview.invalidateViews();
            gridview.postDelayed(swapImages, Tragaperras.intervaloMuestraImagen);       
        }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOveflow puede que sea mas facil para los usuarios que puedan responder a tu pregunta si añades algo de codigo sobre todo las partes que mencionas de mayor relevancia en tu pregunta, lo ideal seria que pudiera proveer un mvce http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Saludos

Comment: Si ejecutas la actividad nuevamente aunque tienes definido el refrescado cada x tiempo ya no se ejecuta al mismo intervalo de tiempo? eso es algo raro, podrías agregar código por favor?

Comment: ok imagino que el handler no esta definido en la actividad que se cierra, en donde tienes definido el handler?

Comment: Jaja, me doy por bienvenida con "a", que soy una chica ;). He subido parte del código para que podáis ver mejor qué es a lo que me refiero.

Comment: Por cierto Elenasys no tengo muy claro a qué te refieres con la implementación del handler... Aquí utilizo como manejador el propio grid para indicarle que salte el runnable. No sé si es a eso a lo que te referías...

Comment: Ante todo, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estás teniendo es que al hacer el onBackPressed() no estás parando el hilo que tienes en ejecución, por lo tanto cuando inicias de nuevo la actividad se inicia otra vez dicho hilo, por eso ocurre que tarda menos tiempo en refrescar las imágenes. Yo te recomiendo usar la interface **[ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)** y **[Future](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)**, aquí un ejemplo:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Future<?> future = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, INITIAL_DELAY, INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

En tu caso quedaría así:

```
Future<?> future = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(swapImages, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Por último para cancelarlo tienes que usar la propiedad **future.cancel()** que te recomiendo usar en los ciclos de vida en vez de en el onBackPressed():

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (future != null && !future.isCancelled()) future.cancel(true);
}
```

Esto es todo, espero que te ayude.
Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya lo he solucionado, llamando en onBackPressed al método removeCallbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos por vuestras aportaciones, pero ya lo he solucionado. 
Simplemente sería añadir en el método onBackPressed la siguiente línea:

```
gridview.removeCallbacks(swapImages);
```

Comment: Ponlo mejor como te comentan en onDestroy()

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacerlo usando un Handler:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Thread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            //Aqui el contenido del hilo
                        }
                    }).start(), 500);
```

Básicamente esto lo que hace es ejecutar un hilo pasado un tiempo, en este caso 500 ms y ejecutaría el bloque de código que hay donde pone el comentario, en tu caso actualizar la vista.

Ten en cuenta que no puedes cambiar cosas de la vista desde hilos que estén fuera de la actividad. Debes ingeniártelas para hacerlo o usar un bus de eventos. Hay mucha info sobre eso en google.

Suerte!

Comment: He subido parte de mi código en mi duda. el runnable que utilizo está dentro de la propia actividad que cierro, y la invocación que hago del timer la hago indicándoselo en el postDelayed del propio grid. ¿Es eso incorrecto?

Comment: Claro, el problema es que no puedes modificar una vista desde un hilo que no sea el hilo de ejecución principal de la aplicación. Esto es común en casi todas las interfaces gráficas. WPF, IOS, Android, JAVAFX ETC...
Es muy común usar un Bus de eventos que básicamente lo que hace es ejecutar el cambio en un momento del hilo principal. Pero tambien hay más formas de hacer los cambios sin usar el Bus.

Answer (score 0):

> ejecuto cada cierto tiempo, y es siempre el mismo (ej: 500
>   milisegundos) y no lo varío en ningún sitio del código.

Puedo comentarte que en realidad si varia el tiempo y depende del estado de la variable `Tragaperras.ganado()` :

```
        }else if (estado == 2){
            imageadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gridview.setAdapter(imageadapter);
            gridview.invalidateViews();
            gridview.postDelayed(swapImages, (Tragaperras.ganado() ? 5000:1000));
            estado = 3;
```

Si `Tragaperras.ganado()` es verdadero habra un delay de 5 segundos (5000ms), si `Tragaperras.ganado()` es falso habra un delay de 1 segundo (1000ms)

Si deseas que no cambie el tiempo debes tener un valor fijo, por ejemplo si deseas tarde 1 segundo siempre:

```
 gridview.postDelayed(swapImages, (1000));
```

Comment: Tenía que haber puntualizado que mi duda es para el estado 1.

Comment: Digamos que en el estado 1 se están mostrando las imágenes y refrescándolas cada 500 milisegundos. Si el usuario no interactúa con la aplicación se deberían de refrescar el grid como una tragaperras, cosa que hace correctamente, hasta que si pulso el botón atrás y se ejecuta onBackPressed. En este método, guarda e inicia la actividad previa a ésta. Desde la nueva actividad que se abre, se vuelve a iniciar la actividad PantallaTragaperrasBotonera en el estado 1 y aquí es donde ya no se están refrescando bien las imágenes.

Comment: @Lirulis si el estado 1 tiene únicamente gridview.postDelayed(swapImages,0); has depurado y verificado en verdad tiene "estado" valor de 1?

Comment: Disculpa, pero no es en el estado 1 donde se refresca el grid sino en el primer if. Y está comprobado que entra y refresca las imágenes. Logueé todo el comportamiento para ver que se ejecutara correctamente la lógica de negocio y fue donde me percaté que lo que estaba pasando era que el runnable no se ejecutaba en el intervalo de 500 milisegundos que tenía establecido, sino cada cuanto le daba la gana y no una cantidad fija. Podría variar en 100, 200, 400, 300, 100, 500... milisegundos...

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aportación. Se solucionaba con un removeCallBacks en el método onBackPressed.